# Make entire div a link with text aligned right?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a div that aligns text to the right (With align-items:flex-end).

Because the link text starts only at the right part of the div, the left part of the DIV is not a link.

I know I can solve this with adding "OnClick" function to the DIV, but my problem is that I need to support also Middle button click. (That opens a new TAB)

With CSS, can I make the entire div a link even though the text is aligned to the right?

```css
.list_text{
  cursor:pointer;
  display:flex;
  border:2px solid black;
  align-items:flex-end;
  flex-direction:column;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="list_text">
  <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">If I click left to this text, can this still be a link?</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `list_text` class on `a` tag. check updated snippet below..

```css
.list_text {
  display:flex;
  border:2px solid black;
  align-items:flex-end;
  flex-direction:column;
  width:100%;     
}
```

```html
<div><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank" class="list_text">If I click left to this text, can this still be a link?</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the link 100% wide and align the text to the right.

```css
.list_text {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid black;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.list_text a {
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
}

.list_text a:hover {
  /* for demo */
  background: lightblue
}
```

```html
<div class="list_text"><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">If I click left to this text, can this still be a link?</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the container div and add class `.list_text` to your anchor tag. Check the code for reference.

```css
.list_text {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid black;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" class="list_text" target="_blank">If I click left to this text, can this still be a link?</a>
```

Hope this help.